# Complex LINQ sorting with groups

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I am trying to sort a list of items according to the following (simplified) rules:

I'll each item has the following properties:

```
 Id (int), 
 ParentId (int?), 
 Name (string)
```

ParentID is a self-join ForeignKey to Id. If an item has a ParentId, then the parent will also exist in the list.

I need to sort the list so that all items which have a parent, appear immediately after their parent. Then all items will be sorted by Name.

So if I had the following:

```
 Id: 1, ParentId: null, Name: Pi
 Id: 2, ParentId: null, Name: Gamma
 Id: 11, ParentId: 1, Name: Charlie
 Id: 12, ParentId: 1, Name: Beta
 Id: 21, ParentId: 2, Name: Alpha
 Id: 22, ParentId: 2, Name: Omega
```

Then I would want them sorted as follows:

> Ids: 2, 21, 22, 1, 12, 11

At the moment the best I can come up with is to sort by Name first, and then Group by ParentId as follows:

```
var sortedItems = itemsToSort.OrderBy(x=> x.Name).GroupBy(x=> x.ParentId);
```

My starting plan was then as follows: (in non functioning code)

```
var finalCollection = new List<Item>

var parentGroup = sortedItems.Where(si => si.Key == null);

foreach(parent in parentGroup)
{
   finalCollection.Add(parent);
   foreach(child in sortedItems.Where(si => si.Key == parent.Id)
   {
      finalCollection.Add(child);
   }
}
```

However, parentGroup is not

```
 IEnumerable<Item>
```

so this does not work.

I feel there is an simpler, more concise way of achieving this, but currently it's eluding me - can anyone help?

Comment: parentGroup certainly will be `IEnumerable<>` - what gives you the impression it isnt?

Comment: Are there only top-level items and first-level children, or also deeper levels?

Comment: @Jamiec: darn it - my angled brackets have been hidden - let me correct

Comment: Only 2 levels - parents and their children

Comment: Are the IDs always prefixed with the ID of their parent?

Comment: @dtb: no - that was for clarity - maybe it just confuses??

Comment: @BonyT - It should be an `IGrouping<int,Item>` which itself would inherit from `IEnumerable<Item>` so you can treat it as if it were an `IEnumerable<Item>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have two levels you can do it like this:

```
var lookup = itemsToSort.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToLookup(x => x.ParentId, x => x);
var parents = lookup[null];
var sortedItems = parents.SelectMany(x => new[] { x }.Concat(lookup[x.Id]));
```

Intially items are sorted by name ensuring that when they are later split into groups they stay sorted.

Then a lookup table is created allowing to lookup by `ParentId`. The parents identified by having a `null ParentId` are then joined with their children using `SelectMany` and the lookup table is used to find the children. The parent is inserted before the children to get the desired sequence.

If you want to solve the general case with more than two levels you need to employ recursion. Here is a way to recursively get the substree for a node:

```
IEnumerable<Item> GetSubtreeForParent(Item parent, ILookup<Int32?, Item> lookup) {
  yield return parent;
  foreach (var child in lookup[parent.Id])
    foreach (var descendant in GetSubtreeForParent(child, lookup))
      yield return descendant;
}
```

The code is almost the same as the simpler case above:

```
var lookup = itemsToSort.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToLookup(x => x.ParentId, x => x);
var parents = lookup[null];
var sortedItems = parents.SelectMany(x => GetSubtreeForParent(x, lookup));
```

By using a recursive lambda you can even do it all "inline":

```
var lookup = itemsToSort.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToLookup(x => x.ParentId, x => x);
// Declare Func to allow recursion.
Func<Int32?, IEnumerable<Item>> getSubTreeForParent = null;
getSubTreeForParent =
  id => lookup[id].SelectMany(x => new[] { x }.Concat(getSubTreeForParent(x.Id)));
var sortedItems = getSubTreeForParent(null);
```

Comment: I like the look of this approach - thank you - I will try it out.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand your question you want to order the results by parent name (if it's a parent) and then by child name (if it's a child), but you want all children to appear in the list after their respective parent.

This should do the trick:

**Updated** to address the issue that `@Martin Liversage` mentioned.

```
var query = from item in itemsToSort
            let parent = itemsToSort.Where(i => i.Id == item.ParentId).FirstOrDefault()
            //get the name of the item's parent, or the item itself if it is a parent
            let parentName = (parent != null) ? parent.Name : item.Name
            //get the name of the child (use null if the item isn't a child)
            let childName = (parent != null) ? item.Name : null
            orderby parentName, childName
            select item;

var finalCollection = query.ToList();
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: Good point, I've now updated my answer to address that problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using:

```
list.Select(i => 
      new {Parent=list.Where(x => x.Id == i.ParentId).FirstOrDefault(), Item = i})
    .OrderBy(i => i.Parent == null ? i.Item.Name : i.Parent.Name + i.Item.Name)
    .Select(i => i.Item)
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/rundotnet?code=WMEZ40628

Output is:

```
2
21
22
1
12
11
```

Comment: All items, including Parents are sorted by Name - so Parent 2 is before Parent 1 due to the name sorting.

Comment: But no worries - I can handle that complication - Your answer provides the logic i couldn't see - genius - thanks.

Comment: Ah missed the "Then sorted by name" requirement. I'll check that out now

Comment: This will break if any of the parents have a name that is a concatenation of another parent and one of its children. Try to rename `Pi` to `GammaAlpha` and see the output.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with DoctaJonez's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360136/complex-linq-sorting-with-groups/7360389#7360389) for 2 level.

It can be extended to n levels like so:

```
Func<int?,Item> lookup = id => list.Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

Func<Item,string> makeSortString = null;
makeSortString = i => i.ParentId == null ? i.Name : makeSortString(lookup(i.ParentId)) + i.Name;

list.OrderBy(makeSortString).ToList();
```

Comment: This will break if any of the parents have a name that is a concatenation of another parent and one of its children. Try to rename `Pi` to `GammaAlpha` and see the output.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
var parentGroup = sortedItems.Where(si => si.Key == null).ToList()
```

will make `parentGroup` `IEnumerable<Item>` .

You will loose laziness on the top level, but i think it's fine due to the context.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var lookup = items.ToLookup(x => x.ParentId);

Func<int?, IEnumerable<Item>> f =  null;
f = ni =>
    from a in lookup[ni].OrderBy(x => x.Name)
    from b in (new [] { a }).Concat(f(a.Id))
    select b;
```

And then to get the sorted list do this:

```
var sorted = f(null);
```

Simple. :-)